# Simple code producing so much error report

Tags: haskell, statistics

I am trying to do MannWhitney-U test as described [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Test-MannWhitneyU.html). Following is my code:

```
import Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector.Unboxed as VU
import Statistics.Test.MannWhitneyU

sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4]
sampleB = [2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, 3.0, 4.0, 5.0, 6]

main = do 
    putStrLn "\nResult of mannWhitneyUtest: "
    print (mannWhitneyUtest SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB) )
```

However, the error is much longer than above code:

```
[1 of 1] Compiling Main             ( rnmann.hs, rnmann.o )

rnmann.hs:6:12: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘1.0’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Fractional t0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include sampleA :: [t0] (bound at rnmann.hs:6:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus four instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 1.0
      In the expression: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, ....]
      In an equation for ‘sampleA’: sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ....]

rnmann.hs:6:47: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘4’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num t0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include sampleA :: [t0] (bound at rnmann.hs:6:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 4
      In the expression: [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0, ....]
      In an equation for ‘sampleA’: sampleA = [1.0, 2.0, 3.0, ....]

rnmann.hs:7:12: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘2.0’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Fractional t0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include sampleB :: [t0] (bound at rnmann.hs:7:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Fractional Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Fractional Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus four instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 2.0
      In the expression: [2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, ....]
      In an equation for ‘sampleB’: sampleB = [2.0, 4.0, 5.0, ....]

rnmann.hs:7:47: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘6’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Num t0)’ from being solved.
      Relevant bindings include sampleB :: [t0] (bound at rnmann.hs:7:1)
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Num Integer -- Defined in ‘GHC.Num’
        instance Num Double -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        instance Num Float -- Defined in ‘GHC.Float’
        ...plus two others
        ...plus 13 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the expression: 6
      In the expression: [2.0, 4.0, 5.0, 5.0, ....]
      In an equation for ‘sampleB’: sampleB = [2.0, 4.0, 5.0, ....]

rnmann.hs:11:16: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘mannWhitneyUtest’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Ord t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Ord Ordering -- Defined in ‘GHC.Classes’
        instance Ord Integer
          -- Defined in ‘integer-gmp-1.0.0.1:GHC.Integer.Type’
        instance Ord PositionTest -- Defined in ‘Statistics.Test.Types’
        ...plus 26 others
        ...plus 25 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(mannWhitneyUtest
            SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print
          (mannWhitneyUtest
             SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB))
      In the expression:
        do { putStrLn
               "\n\
               \Result of mannWhitneyUtest: ";
             print
               (mannWhitneyUtest
                  SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB)) }

rnmann.hs:11:47: error:
    • No instance for (Fractional (Statistics.Types.PValue Double))
        arising from the literal ‘0.05’
    • In the second argument of ‘mannWhitneyUtest’, namely ‘0.05’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(mannWhitneyUtest
            SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print
          (mannWhitneyUtest
             SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB))

rnmann.hs:11:75: error:
    • Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from a use of ‘VU.fromList’
      prevents the constraint ‘(Unbox t0)’ from being solved.
      Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.
      These potential instances exist:
        instance Unbox () -- Defined in ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base’
        instance (Unbox a, Unbox b) => Unbox (a, b)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base’
        instance (Unbox a, Unbox b, Unbox c) => Unbox (a, b, c)
          -- Defined in ‘Data.Vector.Unboxed.Base’
        ...plus 9 others
        ...plus 16 instances involving out-of-scope types
        (use -fprint-potential-instances to see them all)
    • In the fourth argument of ‘mannWhitneyUtest’, namely
        ‘(VU.fromList sampleB)’
      In the first argument of ‘print’, namely
        ‘(mannWhitneyUtest
            SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB))’
      In a stmt of a 'do' block:
        print
          (mannWhitneyUtest
             SamplesDiffer 0.05 (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB))
```

I think the key problem is how to mention 0.05 as the Pvalue.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: This is not output, these are compilation errors.

Comment: Yes, I meant error report.

Comment: An explicit type signature on `sampleA` would have helped you find this error.  As 
a rule of thumb: when type error messages are confusing, add more type signatures.  It usually doesn't fix the problem, but it improves the error messages.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can not use `0.05` as [**`PValue`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Types.html#t:PValue), you can use the [**`mkPValue :: (Ord a, Num a) => a -> PValue a`**](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/statistics-0.15.0.0/docs/Statistics-Types.html#v:mkPValue) to construct a `PValue`:

```
import Statistics.Types(mkPValue)

main = do 
    putStrLn "\nResult of mannWhitneyUtest: "
    print $
       mannWhitneyUtest SamplesDiffer (mkPValue 0.05) (VU.fromList sampleA) (VU.fromList sampleB)
```

This prints as result:

```
Result of mannWhitneyUtest: 
Just Significant
```

Answer (score 3):

Here's the super relevant bits of the error report.

> Ambiguous type variable ‘t0’ arising from the literal ‘4’
>
> Probable fix: use a type annotation to specify what ‘t0’ should be.

Is it an `Int`, `Double`, `Float`? The compiler can't tell since 2 it is ambiguous.

Adding a type signature ought to fix things.

```
sampleA :: [Double]
```

Comment: I never needed to do this in my earlier examples.